Why my Raspberry, goes offline, after wifi router internet cable is unplugged
Situation looks as follow:

I have my raspberry pi connected to the wifi network. I have internet access from raspberry.
I have my laptop with Ubuntu 21 in the same wifi network. I have internet access from laptop.
I can see Raspberry from laptop via SSH.
Then, intentionally, I unplug the internet cable from wifi router.
After that, I do not have any connection with Raspberry, and laptop wifi icon dissapears - what is strange, because wifi router is still alive, but it just doesn't not have Internet connection.

I want to have wireless connection from computer with my raspberry, what I have to do?

get a different router
